# What is the best practice for the Performance of the Query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance, query-performance

On this [Table](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4c36a8/56/0) I use this Script:

```
$SQL = "
SELECT id, col
FROM t
ORDER BY CASE WHEN 'A B C D E' LIKE CONCAT(col, '%') THEN col END DESC;
";
$stmt = $connect->prepare($SQL);
$stmt->execute();
if ($stmt->rowCount > 0) {
    .    .  PULL_DATA  .    .
} else {
    echo 'No Data Pulled';
}
```

I used `ORDER BY` because I wanted to pull the important data first, Which is anything related to col = `A B C D E` THEN `A B C D` THEN `A B C` THEN `A B` THEN `A`

**BUT** If none of those `col =` values exists, to pull the data that not-related to this set of string, So if col of id `1, 2, 7, 5` I still get the other records to use, Right now this Query seems not to be possible to Optimize at all, So I thought about the following Script which uses `WHERE` instead of `ORDER BY` on the [Query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4c36a8/62/0):

```
$SQL = "
SELECT id, col
FROM t
WHERE 'A B C D E' LIKE CONCAT(col, '%')
ORDER BY col DESC;
";
$stmt = $connect->prepare($SQL);
$stmt->execute();
if ($stmt->rowCount > 0) {
    .    .  PULL_DATA  .    .
} else {
    $SQL = "
    SELECT id, col
    FROM t
    ORDER BY col DESC;
    ";
    $stmt = $connect->prepare($SQL);
    $stmt->execute();
    if ($stmt->rowCount > 0) {
        .    .  PULL_DATA  .    .
    } else {
        echo 'No Data Pulled';
    }
}
```

Is this a Good method to maintain performance or is there a better way?

---

To prevent confusion, the `A B C D E` isn't a **static** string but **variable**,

And it is **not** always letters,

it can be words like `Hello My World` where the Query orders the values by `Hello My World` then `Hello My` then `Hello` And this Query is built on this [Question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/204323/splitting-a-string-and-order-by-desc-its-matching-values)

Comment: But is it always in order?  Or can it be 'S N A F U' instead of 'A F N S U'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First Query**

Well, the query:

```
SELECT id, col
  FROM t
  ORDER BY CASE WHEN 'A B C D E' LIKE CONCAT(col, '%') THEN col END DESC;
```

selects all the rows of the table. There's no optimization you can use here, since the `order by` expression changes per query. No index can be created that will help on any order.

**Second Query**

The second query can be optimized. If you know that `col` has a minimum length then it can be optimized, even if it's 1 character long (hopefully longer).

For this example, let's assume `col` has a minimum length of three characters. Then I would create an index for those three head characters as:

```
alter table t add (col_head as substring(col, 1, 3));

create index ix1_t on t (col_head);
```

Then add an extra condition, that seems redundant. This extra condition will try to use an **Index Range Scan** table access mode that is much faster than a **Full Table Scan**:

```
SELECT id, col
  FROM t
  where col_head = substring('A B C D E', 1, 3) 
    and 'A B C D E' LIKE CONCAT(col, '%')
  ORDER BY col DESC;
```

**Note 1:** the parameter 'A B C D E' is added twice in the SQL.

**Note 2:** before and after the change, retrieve the execution plan MySQL is using, and see if there are any differences. To retrieve the execution plan run:

```
explain <my_query>
```